# Progress bar with .delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dyph8jh/10/)
I want to make a progress bar fill up 25% per second. My current code makes it go to 100% and stay there on click. I'm not sure if it's best to use jquery or css. Or if there is an easier way to do it.
Also how can I make an action occur multiple times from one .click. Like you click battle and it hits the monster, then waits for the progress bar to fill, then hits the monster again and so on?

```
$('#battle').click(function() {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage");
  $('#bar').val(25).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(50).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(75).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(100);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go!
https://jsfiddle.net/6nrjw0Le/

For your example I am using

```
setTimeout()
```

Your example edited.

```
var progress = function(sec){
    var interval = 250;//milliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){
    sec = sec+25;
        $('#bar').val(sec);
        if(sec < 100)
            progress(sec);//call self with new value
    },interval)
}

$('#battle').click(function() {
    $('#dam').html("You have hit the " + $('#monsters').val() + " for 5 damage");
  /*$('#bar').val(25).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(50).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(75).delay(1000);
  $('#bar').val(100);*/
  progress(0);//initialize progress bar
});
```

delay() is asynchronous. Putting one delay after another doesn't mean you get the execution after first one is complete.

Comment: "delay() is asynchronous" - more specifically `.delay()` only applies to animations.  Setting the `.val()` is not an animation.   `setTimeout` is the way to go (as in this answer ofc)

Comment: How would I make the progress bar go back to 0 value after each fill up?